# is it possible to debug 2 clients of a remote (remoting) server on the same pc?

Tags: c#, debugging, networking, remoting

i want to test my application which involves one server and a few clients.
it is necessary that 2 clients at least will be connected to the server in order to test it's functionality.
i succeeded to run one client and the server on the same machine and debug it.
is it possible to run 2 clients at the same times?
the problem is that the remote server uses a specific port for remoting, and i believe that in order to run two clients i need 2 ports.
is there a simpler solution?
thanks
Tal

Comment: Are you trying to debug the client, the server, or both?

Comment: both.
im want to run 2 clients and the server and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it would be simplest to have a second debugging machine with it's own installation of Visual Studio - perhaps you could run the second one in Virtual PC?

Comment: what do you mean by virtual pc?
is it a software i have to get?

Comment: Yes: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=04D26402-3199-48A3-AFA2-2DC0B40A73B6

Answer (score 0):

You can always run the client project/solution in another instance of visual studio and debug it. if you are running the client on a specific port/channel then you will need to change the port/channel so that there are no conflicts. I would imagine that you have this information in a config file so it should be fairly trivial to update.

Comment: the problem is that by changing the port i am changing the architecture of the application, since it assumes all the remoting calls by the clients are done through the same port.

Comment: i tried to configure the server to accept remote calls on two different ports, but i got a runtime error which said ""tcp" channel is already registered". is it possible to build a server which get remote calls on two different ports?

Comment: i was referring to the client channels not the server ones. Are you building a P2P app?